# A unsychronized Collection object that contain some data, want synchronisation wrapper but don't want reference to original object

Tags: java, collections, synchronization

I'm currently studying Java Collections on [Java tutorial oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/wrapper.html)  and have encountered the following paragraph

> Each of these methods returns a synchronized (thread-safe) `Collection` backed up by the specified collection. To guarantee serial access, *all* access to the backing collection must be accomplished through the returned collection. The easy way to guarantee this is not to keep a reference to the backing collection. Create the synchronized collection with the following trick.
>
> ```
> List<Type> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Type>());
> ```

I was just wondering, what happen if I have an instance of Collection (the backing collection) that has not been synchronized and **contain some data**, and I want to turn this instance of Collection (the backing collection) into a synchronized collection, but does not want to keep a reference to the backing collection. How could this be done? Is it possible? If yes, is this something that people would normally do?

Comment: If you plan on changing the state of the collection, why not make a copy of it first?

Comment: Sure, you can wrap an existing collection. It's *preferable* not to hold a reference to the backing collection, as that ensures it won't be accidentally modified.

Comment: your question is not clear .. you can get a new list and dump the old one easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to guarantee that you don't keep a reference to the backing collection, exit the scope of your reference.

In other words, declare the reference to the backing array inside a block, and make sure that the reference is passed *only* to the `Collections.synchronizedList()` method. When that block is exited, the reference is lost, and you can be sure that only the synchronized wrapper refers to the backing collection.

This is not a common approach, but it won't cause concurrency problems as long as no changes are made to the backing collection after wrapping it. It might, however, cause some arguments from your colleagues who know that the cited idiom is safe, but aren't sure about your innovation. That alone may be a good enough reason to add elements through the wrapper, rather than the backing collection.

Here's an example:

```
class MyObj {

  private final List<Type> list;

  MyObj(/* Some arguments that control initial list contents */) {
    List<Type> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
    tmp.add(...);
    list = Collections.synchronizedList(tmp);
  } /* Reference to `tmp` is lost, safety is ensured. */

}
```